# Evaluation of given definite integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Evaluate the integral"

$$\int _{0}^{1} \frac{7x^4+5x^2+4x}{\sqrt {x^3+x+1}} dx$$

I am not able to proceed in this question. Could someone give me some hint?

Edit: Initially as I wasn't able to proceed and that is why I couldn't show my work but I did not requested for answer but some hint and then with little  suggestion from @Andreas I was able to solve the question and posted answer here as well.

I don't think it should be put on hold as an off-topic because even after downvotes from some users it is still having $+2$ upvotes. Please consider my request.

Comment: Have you tried Wolfram yet? What does it spit out?

Comment: Here is it your answer. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+(7x%5E4%2B5x%5E2%2B4x)%2F(sqrt(x%5E3%2Bx%2B1))dx

Comment: What substitutions have you thought of using?

Comment: It's a good idea to use Wolfram's result and do "reverse engineering" to arrive there, using the usual integration rules.

Comment: @Andreas Thank you for the suggestion. Dividing and multiplying by $x^2$ will do the trick. But I think it is tough to obverse it without looking at the answer.

Comment: @Mathematics How did you do "reverse engineering"?

Answer (score 4):

With Andreas's suggestion, I have reached the answer.

We divide and multiply by $x^2$, the expression inside square root in denominator

becomes $x^7+x^5+x^4$ and we set $x^7+x^5+x^4=t$ to get $(7x^6+5x^4+4x^3).dx=dt$ which is present in numerator.